# Reference as a parameter

Tags: c++, string, vector, reference, constants

Hi I am trying to change contents of my vec passed as a reference, I am pretty new to this concept and can't see what's wrong with my code:

```
std::string pluralize(std::string const& word) {
if (uncountables.count(word) > 0) {
    return word;
}

for (auto const& r : rules) {
    if (r.matches(word)) {
        return r.pluralize(word);
    }
}

// The last rule is fully generic "append s" rule, so we cannot
// get here unless something is seriously wrong.
throw std::runtime_error("Word '" + word + "' did not match any rule");
}

std::vector<std::string> pluralize(std::vector<std::string> const& words) {

for (auto word : words) {
    word = pluralize(word);
    std::cout << word << " word from pluralize called with vec" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << words[0] << " 0 word from pluralize called with vec" << std::endl;
std::cout << words[1] << " 1 word from pluralize called with vec" << std::endl;
return words;
}
```

When method pluralize is called with a string as a parameter, it works as expected: changing value of passed word. 
When called with a vec it doesn't change values of passed strings.
These are my test cases:

Code works fine for these test cases:

```
SECTION("Respects capitalization") {
    REQUIRE(pluralize("Car") == "Cars");
    REQUIRE(pluralize("Mouse") == "Mice");
    REQUIRE(pluralize("German") == "Germans");
    }
```

These test cases fail:

```
REQUIRE(
        pluralize({"Car", "Mouse", "German"}) == make_vec({"Cars", "Mice", "Germans"})
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify `words`, since it's `const`.
You're not noticing this because you're not modifying it - the deduced type in `for (auto word : words)` is `std::string`, not `std::string&`.

You can for instance copy the input and modify your copy:

```
std::vector<std::string> pluralize(std::vector<std::string> const& words)
{
    std::vector<std::string> plurals = words;
    for (auto& word : plurals) {
        word = pluralize(word);
    }
    return plurals;
}
```

or gather the pluralized words in a loop:

```
std::vector<std::string> pluralize(std::vector<std::string> const& words)
{
    std::vector<std::string> plurals;
    for (const auto& word : words) {
        plurals.push_back(pluralize(word));
    }
    return plurals;
}
```

or use `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<std::string> pluralize(std::vector<std::string> const& words)
{
    std::vector<std::string> plurals;
    std::transform(words.begin(), words.end(), std::back_inserter(plurals), pluralize);
    return plurals;
}
```

or some other solution...

Comment: thanks for the reply, std::transform looks like an interesting solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for (auto word : words) {
    word = pluralize(word);
}
```

The variable `word` here is a string *value*. You are changing that value but that does not change the word in the vector. Try using a reference:

```
for (auto& word : word) {
    word = pluralize(word);
}
```

`auto` does not deduce a reference.

**Edit:**  You can't modify an element in the vector as you have it as a reference-to-const. One way of fixing it would be to take a copy of the vector. The easiest way of doing that is to modify the signature of the function to pass-by-value:

```
std::vector<std::string> pluralize(std::vector<std::string> words) {
    for (auto& word : words) {
        word = pluralize(word);
    }
    return words;
}
```

Comment: i tried that but it gives me an error: No viable overloaded '=', I guess it's because of the const keyword.

Comment: @YevgenPonomarenko then don't pass the vector by reference-to-const . Pass by value.